# Toggle the css class when clicked on checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, input, checkbox

I have a asp.net gridview which forms a table when run at server. I have a html checkbox in each table row with the same id .

The table is as follows,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="column">
            <div id="favicon" class="class-icon">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkSelected" onclick=check(); ">
            </div>

      </td>
      <td class="column ">
            <div id="favicon " class="class-icon ">
                        <input type="checkbox " id="chkSelected " onclick=check();">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The gridview is bound whith several row. When I checked on a checkbox I need to toggle the css class of the parent div of that respective checked checkbox. But not all other checkboxes.

Here is the code I tried,

```
$("#chkSelected").closest('tr').find('div').toggleClass('active');
```

But it didnot work. Tried with the `parent()` function also. 
 Please anyone help me in achieving this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: invalid `#1, #1, #1` same ids can't be used. better to use class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of HTML must have unique IDs

```
$(".chkSelected").live("click",function(){
    $(this).parent('div').toggleClass("active");  
});
```

Refer http://jsfiddle.net/pLxGk/3/

Answer (score 1):

ID of an element must be unique, use class instead to group similar elements

```
        <td class="column">
            <div class="class-icon favicon">
                <input type="checkbox" class="chkSelected"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then use jQuery event handlder

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.chkSelected').change(function () {
        //the targeted div is the parent, so you can use .parent(), no need to use .closest(...).find(...)
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
        //$(this).closest('tr').find('div').toggleClass('active');
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun.  The Checkbox that I am using cannot have unique id. I am using a clientside control and the checkbox which is wrapped in a gridview item template. So, all the checkboxs will have the same id.

Comment: @Mahe then remove the id property... we don't need it anyway

Comment: It gives this error in the browser console, "$(...).parent.toggleClass is not a function.   Any more suggestions please. I am in a deadlock.

Comment: @Mahe sorry, it should have been `$(this).parent().toggleClass('active');`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using:

```
$("#chkSelected").parent('div.class-icon').toggleClass('active');
```

And you should have unique ids for checkboxes.